# Is there a specific order to read Tom Clancy's works?

Tags: reading-order, tom-clancy

I found a bunch of the books, I think the first one was *The Hunt for Red October*, but then I don't know what's next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The Hunt for Red October* is the fourth book in a (currently) 24-long series, known as the [Jack Ryan series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/171703-jack-ryan-universe) by Tom Clancy. That link has the books by publication date, but you might prefer them by [chronological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryanverse#Chronological_order):

> Without Remorse (1970)
>
> Patriot Games (1981)
>
> Red Rabbit (circa spring of 1983)
>
> The Hunt for Red October (1985)
>
> The Cardinal of the Kremlin (1987)
>
> Clear and Present Danger (1988)
>
> The Sum of All Fears (1991–92)
>
> Debt of Honor (1995–96)
>
> Executive Orders (1996)
>
> Rainbow Six
>
> The Bear and the Dragon (2000)
>
> The Teeth of the Tiger (2005, based on the age of Jack Ryan Jr.)

Clancy has other series, such as the [John Clark series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/101174-john-clark), which encompasses Rainbow Six and other books.

Comment: I read the Hunt for the Red October in 1996, I thinked all of his works were in the Jack Ryan side. Thanks for the answer, it is  very detailed